# Does X11 window transparency via RGBA work on Windows 7 via Cygwin/X?

Tags: windows, cygwin, x11

I would like to have an X11 program with arbitrarily-shaped transparent areas using RGBA (so that whatever is underneath those area shows through) running on Cygwin/X on Windows 7.

Is this possible? If so, it is efficient ie the transparency gets mapped to Windows' analogous support for opacity or transparency keys somehow (or in some other way)?

Comment: No, as far as I know. What is `xdpyinfo` output? Does server have composite and damage extensions?

Comment: @Andrey Sidorov - thanks, will try that as soon as I have a chance and let you know (am in New York with limited power). Assuming Cygwin/X doesn't have this support, are there other ways to run X11 on Windows with composite/damage support?

Comment: even when there is support for composite/damage extensions you need to run composite manager to get transparent windows - and to integrate with win7 transparency it has to be mix of x11 and win32 api, I'm not sure such compositor exist (write your own! :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

You might wish to take a look at the very experimental [XtoW](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-xfree-announce/2012-12/msg00003.html) compositing WM.

This is 'efficient' in the sense that X window image with alpha channel is simply drawn into the native window.